# foreach loop is not working after print array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've tried to loop of following array.

```
Array
(
    [mech_info] => Array
        (
            [make] => Amaka
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2001
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test one
                            [1] => test fix
                            [2] => Hamour
                            [3] => Imagica
                        )    
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2002
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test Two
                        )    
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2014
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test three
                        )    
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2015
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => test four
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)

Array
(
    [mech_info] => Array
        (
            [make] => PRI
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [year] => 2005
                    [model] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => PRIMODE
                            [1] => Temp Pri
                            [2] => primode
                            [3] => yyy
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

I want to do it with foreach loop. I have tried by following code but it is not show anything except

```
 `print_r($_POST['mech_show']);`.

       $all_make_model= $_POST['mech_show'];
        $all_make_model_data = $all_make_model['mech_info'];

    foreach ($all_make_model_data as $key => $mec_value) {
        echo "string";
        echo $meta_value['make'];
    }


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST['mech_show']);


    exit();
```

also not able to go under `foreach` and data not print in loop.

given me error

> Notice: Undefined index: mech_info

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
```

i also trie this way but

```
$all_make_model= $_POST['mech_show'];
$all_make_model_data = $_POST['mech_info'];

    foreach ($all_make_model as $key => $mec_value) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($mec_value['make']);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($all_make_model['mech_info']);
```

but it's `showing Warning:  Illegal string offset 'mech_info' in ..`

I don't know if my code is wrong or I'm missing something anyone pls help me.

Thank You

Comment: typo `echo $meta_value['make'];` should be `echo $mec_value['make']`

Comment: `foreach ($all_make_model_data as $key => $mec_value) {
    echo "string";
    echo $mec_value['make'];
}`

Comment: can you var_dump your mech_show? I tried to create your object, and i got an array of empty array

Comment: ok let i do this.

Comment: @GiuServ i tried using var dump it's showing me full array.

Comment: @maddy can you post it in the question, so i'll try it?

Comment: @GiuServ i already post array and what i did for it in my queastion.

Comment: @maddy So please can you show how do you create that object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127867/discussion-between-giuserv-and-maddy).

Answer (score 0):

Some change your `foreach` loop. it `$meta_value['make']` should be `$mec_value['make']`

So,

```
$all_make_model= $_POST['mech_show'];
//$all_make_model_data = $all_make_model['mech_info'];

foreach ($all_make_model as $key => $mec_value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($mec_value['make']);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but nothing display any given me blank.

Comment: given me error like 

Notice: Undefined index: mech_info in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cync/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/functions.php on line 1258

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cync/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/functions.php on line 1260

Comment: and remove `$all_make_model_data = $all_make_model['mech_info'];` this line. no need that. let me know

Comment: try this one echo $mec_value

Comment: @RazibAlMamun i remove that line and now error showing is 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @JYoThI given me error 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: print_r($all_make_model_data); and check it have valid array values ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$all_array=array("mech_info"=>array("make"=>"Amaka",array("year"=>2001,"model"=>array("one","two","three")),array("year"=>2002,"model"=>array("one","two","three")),array("year"=>2003,"model"=>array("one","two","three")),array("year"=>2004,"model"=>array("one","two","three"))),array("mech_info"=>array("make"=>"PRI",array("year"=>2001,"model"=>array("one","two","three")))));

$all_make_model= $all_array;
//$all_make_model_data = $all_make_model['mech_info'];
//print_r($all_make_model['mech_info']);
foreach ($all_make_model['mech_info'] as $key => $mec_value) {
   if(is_numeric($key)) continue;
   echo $mec_value;    // output Amaka
}

exit();
```

Comment: not working given me : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

This Code just work. 
To iterate on multiple mech_info, i added a leave in the array, because otherwise you are tring to create multiple object with the same index.

```
$p = Array('mech_show' => Array(
    0 => Array(
        'mech_info' => Array(
                'make' => 'Amaka',
                '0' => Array(
                        'year' => 2001,
                        'model' => Array(
                                0 => 'Test one',
                                1 => 'test fix',
                                2 => 'Hamour',
                                3 => 'Imagica'
                            )    
                    ),

                '1' => Array(
                        'year' => 2002,
                        'model' => Array(
                                0 => 'Test Two'
                            )    
                    ),

                '2' => Array(
                        'year' => 2014,
                        'model' => Array(
                                0 => 'Test three'
                            )    
                    ),

                '3' => Array(
                        'year' => 2015,
                        'model' => Array
                            (
                                0 => 'test four'
                            )    
                    )    
            )    
        ),
    1=>Array(
        'mech_info' => Array(
                'make' => 'PRI',
                '0' => Array(
                        'year' => 2005,
                        'model' => Array(
                                0 => 'PRIMODE',
                                1 => 'Temp Pri',
                                2 => 'primode',
                                3 => 'yyy'
                            )    
                    )    
            )    
        )
    )
);

$all_make_model= $p['mech_show'];

foreach($all_make_model as $all_make_model_data){
    foreach($all_make_model_data as $mech_info)
    var_dump($mech_info['make']);
}
```

where you have to replace $p with $_POST

Comment: Not working given me : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: the first one or the second foreach? i made a simple php page and it was working. if it doesn't, your object is different, that's why i asked for a var_dump of 'mech_show'